"Scarecrow"'s construction and similar words
In English, most objects that perform an action are called noun verbers (e.g. bottle opener). Scarecrow is a notable exception.
Is there an in-depth explanation for how it came to be? Are there any similarly constructed English words?

Etymonline covers this

Here are some other examples:

Pickpocket
Cutthroat
Turncoat
Spoilsport
Killjoy
Breakwater
Telltale

